# How do i use sort and paginate the table in php

Tags: php

I have the table which list some details from database.I want to sort the whole table when user click on table name I have found http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ which has the exact requirement. But i need to use `pagination` here and also if user clicks on `second page` then click on table name to sort ,`it should come again first page with sorting result`.
Can we use AJAX to sort the result and replace the html of table.Is there any best way to implement this ?
Kindly help me on this

Comment: find in to stackoverflow paginate ajax jquery and you find million of results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it from http://www.datatables.net/